# оптимизация sql запроса с like

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть sql запрос, который очень долго работает из-за поиска лайком

```
SELECT COUNT ( distinct appEvents.id ) FROM appEvents
INNER JOIN eventTypes ON appEvents.EventType = eventTypes.id
LEFT JOIN ipgeolocation ON appEvents.RequestIp = ipgeolocation.ip 
WHERE (EventType = 2 OR EventType = 3 OR EventType = 12 OR EventType = 14 OR EventType = 15 OR EventType 

= 18 OR EventType = 33) AND (Comment Like '%D200-001-00000119%')
```

Искать полный текст нельзя... Можно как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: если там с боков пробелы, то полнотекстовый индекс вероятно вам поможет

Comment: Развивая предыдущий комментарий, можно добавить вот что: для Like '%искомое слово' или Like 'искомое слово%' можно получить практически мгновенный поиск - из за особеннойстей построения индекса. В остальных случаях - хм, самому было бы интересно, как избежать full scan'а...

Comment: этот паттерн у вас вообще постоянный у вас?

Comment: @S.H. вы уверены по поводу `like '%needle'` ?

Comment: @teran - Там можно применить трюк: заводим еще одну колонку в таблице, куда засовываем все строки в "перевернутом виде". Получив запрос на поиск вида like '%needle' преобразуем его в запрос вида like 'eldeen%' и выполняем его по колонке с "перевернутыми строками"

Comment: @S.H.  c "трюками" все понятно. я к вопросу о том, что индекс используется только в поиске `needle%`, дабы вы не вводили людей в заблуждение

Comment: @teran - согласен, надеюсь, мой предыдущий комментарий поясняет, что я имел в виду :-)

Comment: А в чём смысл поиска такого комментария? Может это какая-то осмысленная информация и её имеет смысл вытащить в какие-то отдельные полноценные поля базы, чтобы потом можно было по ним поиск делать, а не вот так странно?

Comment: Проблема в том, что сделать поиск через = я не могу. Так как в поле Comment есть ещё разный текст. = бы решило проблему. Добавление новой колонки хороший вариант. Сейчас буду пробовать, спасибо

Comment: эту новую колонку можно выделить в отдельную таблицу 1к1 на случай разрастания "признаков" (если это целесообразно)

Comment: Данный запрос выполняется при нажатии на handler на сервере с данным номером для поиска комментариев такого вида: %текст% устройство: D200-000-00000001 %текст%

Comment: Думаю, лучшим вариантом будет переработать способ хранения логов (это же логи?) в БД. Использовать Structured Logging. Важные поля, по которым будет осуществляться поиск должны помещаться в отдельные колонки таблицы. То есть номер устройства - это отдельная колонка.